# why is my jquery created element (option) failing html5 validation

Tags: jquery, html, dom, w3c-validation

I'm using jQuery's `append()`, `attr()` and `text()` to add options to my select element via an ajax call.  When I try to validate my page at the w3 validator I'm getting errors on the elements that were created with the `append()` function. Here is the function:

```
$.post("blah.php", function(result) {
    var places = result.split(" ");
    $.each(places, function(key, value) {
        $("#usrplaces")
        .append($("<option><\/option>")
        .attr("value", value)
        .text(value.replace(/\+/g, " ")))
    })
})
```

the validator is showing 4 errors:

```
Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier. (2x)
Attribute value"" not allowed on element option at this point.
Element option without attribute label must not be empty.
```

Why am I getting the errors?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle ??

Comment: the ajax call goes to a php pages that requires session data, I don't think I can get it working in a fiddle.

Comment: Show us a code which you are trying to validate? I've created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpr4kacq/2/ with your JS code and it looks ok.

Comment: Can you show us the data that is returned from blah.php?

Comment: The only part that is failing validation are the options created by jquery.  The select is opened and closed with the script between.  The script is just the tag with the source pointing to my .js file

Comment: @Faust the return is the result of a PHP mysql_query function.  I returns one column with each row deliminated by a space.

Comment: Doesn't matter where it comes from or how it what generated. What are the *values*? I suspect it's choking on something

Comment: BTW, You don't need to escape that slash. And you can just use "<option />"

Comment: You should include a minimal example of the HTML that gives this error.

Comment: The W3 validator doesn’t validate elements added by JavaScript. The problem is in the HTML.

Comment: It does validate elements created by JavaScript. See http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-javascript for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is u need

```
$.each(places, function(key, value) {
    var text = value.replace(/\+/g, " ");
    var newoption = "<option value=\""+value+"\">"+text+"</option>";
    $("#usrplaces").append(newoption);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
.append("<option></option>")
```

Comment: The strings are completely equivalent.